# How to integrate $\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Tags: calculus

How do you integrate the following integral? I have tried u-substitution, but it doesn't work out.

$$\int(x^2-1)^{0.5}dx$$

Comment: The substitution $x=\cosh(t)$ (for $x\geq1$, or $x=-\cosh(t)$ for $x\leq-1$) should work…

Comment: You have seen that I have added a $dx$ to your integral. Without it, it was like a Xmas tree without decoration...

Comment: do you meant $$\int \sqrt{x^2-1}dx$$?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks! I know, it's like eating cereal without milk.

Comment: If you're new to the subject, the substitution $x = \sec(u)$ is probably better suited to you.

Comment: I'm not really new to integration, I am new to trigonometric substitution. I have used u substitution, but not yet trigonomic.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT(My approach)**: We can perform trigonometric substitution by substituting $x =\sec u$ and thus our integral transforms to $\displaystyle\int \sec u\sqrt{\sec^2 u-1} \tan u du = \displaystyle\int \sec u \tan^2 u du =\displaystyle \int \sec^3 u du-\displaystyle \int \sec u du$. Now [using reduction formula for $\sec u$](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?p=47972) in the first integral, the entire integral can be easily solved.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the sec function?

Comment: @Sam Liemburg See here: http://www.mathopenref.com/trigsecant.html

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Answer (score 0):

$I=\int 1\cdot\sqrt{x^2-1}dx$

Put $x = \sec y$

then $dx = \sec y.\tan y dy$

$= \int \sqrt{\sec^2 y-1}. \sec y.\tan y dy$

$= \int \sqrt{\tan^2 y}. \sec y.\tan y dy$

$= \int \tan y. \sec y. \tan y dy$

$= \int \tan^2 y. \sec y dy$

$= \int (\sec^2 y - 1). \sec y dy$

$= \int \sec^3 y dy - \int \sec y dy$

$= \int \sec^3 y dy + log|\sec y + \tan y|$  .......(1)

Now,

$\int \sec^3 y dy=\int \sec y (\sec^2 y dy)$

Put $\tan y = t$

$\sec^2 y dy = dt$

and $\sec y = \sqrt{1+t^2}$

$\int \sqrt{1 + t^2}dt$

$\frac{t\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2} + \frac{\log(t+\sqrt{1+t^2})}{2}$

$t = \tan y$

$\frac{\tan y\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 y}}{2} + \frac{\log(\tan y + \sqrt{1 + \tan^2 y})}{2}$

Now from equation (1)

$= \frac{\tan y \sqrt{1 + \tan^2 y}}{2} + \frac{\log(\tan y + \sqrt{1 + \tan^2 y})}{2} + log|\sec y + \tan y|$

And replace y = $\sec^{-1}x$ and you got answer.

Comment: It's not $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ it's $\sqrt{x^2-1}$.

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh your integral is on the totally wrong track. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

> In $(1,+\infty)$

Put $x=\cosh(t)$.
then, we compute

$$\int \sinh^2(t) dt=\int \frac{1-\cosh(2t)}{2}dt$$

$$=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\sinh(2t)}{4}.$$

> In $(-\infty,-1)$

You put $x=-\cosh(u)$.

Comment: Did you get the sign wrong for $\sinh^2$? (you're saying it's negative).

Comment: What are the cosh and sinh functions? I know cos, sin, tan and their inverse versions, but what are those?

Comment: @SamLiemburg They are hyperbolic functions. you have for example $cosh^2-sinh^2=1$.

Comment: Can I use them on my calculator?

Comment: @SamLiemburg  Yes you can.